# mongodb $where not working

Tags: mongodb, shell, where-clause

I have this type of document:

```
    {
  "_id":ObjectId("527cedf19df815000700123b"),
  "title":"title question",
  "content": "content question",
  "answer": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("527cee379df8155c1300002a"),
      "content": "<p>answer 1<\/p>",
      "total_dislike": NumberInt(10),
      "total_like": NumberInt(20)
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("527d135b9df8152c04005ddd"),
      "content": "<p>answer 2<\/p>",
      "total_dislike": NumberInt(2),
      "total_like": NumberInt(6)
    }
  ]   


}
```

And I want to create a query where `answer.total_dislike > answer.total_like`.

I used this query:

```
> db.Question.find( { $where: "this.answer.total_dislike > this.answer.total_like" } );
```

But it is not working. How could I write a query to return all of the subdocuments where `answer.total_dislike` is greater than `answer.total_like`?

Comment: At a first glance: `this.answer` is an array. It doesn't have `total_dislike` method.

Comment: Using the JavaScript where operator on every document and every array element is not going to perform well as your collection size increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this query is going to perform poorly (it can't use indexes, and must run against every document in the collection), I'd suggest you precalculate the result of the condition when possible and store it as a new field. While it increases the size of your document structure slightly, it would make the queries super fast, especially if the field is indexed:

```
"answer": [
{
  "_id": ObjectId("527cee379df8155c1300002a"),
  "content": "<p>answer 1<\/p>",
  "total_dislike": NumberInt(10),
  "total_like": NumberInt(20),
  "likes_more": Boolean(true)
},
```

Then:

```
db.Question.find(
    { answer: 
        { $elemMatch: 
            { likes_more: false }
        }
    }
);
```

When using a NoSQL database, sometimes you need to consider the problem a bit differently.

The other option would be to do a MapReduce that you update periodically to reflect new Like/Dislike changes. While it's not quite the same given your current structure, you could do the same type of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The `$where` operator won't dig down into the array of subdocuments like you think. You're going to need to use a different operator first. I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try this or a variation of it:

```
db.Question.find(
    { answer: 
        { $elemMatch: 
            { $where: "this.total_dislike > this.total_like" 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: "$elemMatch cannot contain $where expression",

Comment: "Only apply the $where query operator to top-level documents. The $where query operator will not work inside a nested document, for instance, in an $elemMatch query." https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use aggregation framework?

```
 db.Question.aggregate(  
        {$unwind:"$answer"}, 
        {$project:{disliked:{$cond:[{$gt:[{"$answer.total_dislike","$answer.total_like"}], true, false]}, 
                   title:1}
        }, 
        {$match:{disliked:true}}
 )
```